# Google datastore - multiput is failing

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

Currently am trying to attempt multiput using Google datastore in Google cloud environment. Interesting point is that when the python code is run in VirtualBox or AWS environments , it works fine. But when I run the same code in Google Compute environment, it fails with no error or output.

Already tried running the sample snippets.py from google datastore github and that works well in the same environment.

Need your kind inputs to rectify the same. Thanks in advance.

```
     datastore_client = datastore.Client()
     list_var=[]
     with open(name, 'r') as inp:
        for line in inp:
            linecount+=1
            line = line.split(":")
            uid = line[0]
            task_cnt = "task_" + str(linecount)
            task_cnt = datastore.Entity(datastore_client.key('kind_name', uid))
            task_cnt.update({
            'field1': datetime.datetime.now(),
            'field2' : str(line[1]),
            })
            list_var.append(task_cnt)
    datastore_client.put_multi(list_var)
```

Comment: Do you mean that you get no errors in your logs but the data you wrote is not found in Datastore?

Comment: Yes, Y2H.  This same piece of code when run from local workstation is executed successfully and data is updated in datastore, but when i run this from google compute environment, I do not see any output and no errors are generated as well.